# force close when i'm click the button -kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I typed some kivy code about the buying system until I pressed the button I made and the application suddenly force close and i don't know why, can you help me?

my python code

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core import text
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty


class MyGrid(Widget):
tv = ObjectProperty(None) 
pc = ObjectProperty(None)
coin = ObjectProperty(None)

def tv(self):
    coin = 4000
    tv = 3000
    if coin > tv:
     coin - tv
     print("you got the tv", "coin= ", coin)
    if coin < tv:
     print("your coin is minus")

def pc(self):
    coin = 4000
    pc = 5000
    if coin > pc:
        coin - pc
        print("you got the pc", "coin= ", coin)
    if coin < pc:
     print ("your coin is minus")
    
    


class MyApp(App):
def build(self):
    return MyGrid()


if __name__ == "__main__":
MyApp().run()
```

my kivy code

```
<MyGrid>:

tv : tv
pc : pc

GridLayout:
    cols:1
    size: root.width - 200, root.height -200
    pos: 100, 100

    GridLayout:
        cols:2

        Label:
            text: "tv "

        Button:
            id: tv
            text: "3000"
            on_press: root.tv()
    
    GridLayout:
        cols:2

        Label:
            text: "pc"

        Button:
            id: pc
            text: "5000"
            on_press: root.pc()
```

[image: this is the picture]

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Comment: yes i'm get an error masage

Comment: Add the error message to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions are:

1. Make the indentations appropriate,
2. Two most important things:

> i) Establish object reference by `self`,
> ii) The `attributes` and the `methods` might have collision due to their same name (you are calling and using them simultaneously), try changing them.

It turns out, the `attributes'` and `methods'` same name were causing the problem mainly. After changing them it should work as expected.

```py
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core import text
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty



Builder.load_string("""

<MyGrid>:
    tv : tv
    pc : pc

    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        size: root.width - 200, root.height -200
        pos: 100, 100

        GridLayout:
            cols:2

            Label:
                text: "tv "

            Button:
                id: tv
                text: "3000"
                on_press: root.get_tv()
    
        GridLayout:
            cols:2

            Label:
                text: "pc"

            Button:
                id: pc
                text: "5000"
                on_press: root.get_pc()

""")





class MyGrid(Widget):
    tv = ObjectProperty(None)
    pc = ObjectProperty(None)
    coin = ObjectProperty(None)

    def get_tv(self):
        coin = 4000
        tv = 3000
        if coin > tv:
            coin - tv
            print("you got the tv,", "coin= ", coin)
        if coin < tv:
            print("your coin is minus.")

    def get_pc(self):
        coin = 4000
        pc = 5000
        if coin > pc:
            coin - pc
            print("you got the pc,", "coin= ", coin)
        if coin < pc:
            print ("your coin is minus.")
    
    


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return MyGrid()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```